# Como passar um array em uma condição WHERE

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, array

```
$this->db->set('al_reg', $matricula);
$this->db->set('dataagendamento', $dataagendamento);
$this->db->where('cod_lab', $laboratorio);
$this->db->where('cod_horario', $horario_prova);
$this->db->where('cod_data', $data_prova);
$this->db->where('cod_assento', $assento[]);
$this->db->where('al_reg', NULL);
$this->db->update('P_chekin_Geral');
```

Neste model está quase tudo sendo atualizado certinho, apenas o `cod_assento` que é um vetor de 1 a 22 para cada laboratório.

Alguém tem ideia de se há a possibilidade de adicionar um vetor de 22  onde cada cadastro grave em sequência e depois se reinicie? exemplo:

```
lab acessento 
  1        1
  1        2
  1        3..
  1        22
  2        1
  2        2
  2        3..
  2        22
  3        1..
  3        22
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Troque o `where()` convencional pelo `where_in()`, o primeiro apenas compara um valor com uma determinada coluna ex: `WHERE nome = 'fulano'`. Já o segundo compara uma serie de valores com uma coluna a sql gerada seria mais ou menos dessa forma: `WHERE nome IN ('fulano', 'fuleiro', 'joão')`

Mude:

```
$this->db->where('cod_assento', $assento[]);
```

Por:

```
$this->db->where_in('cod_assento', $assento);
```

Comment: tipo, já tenho todos os assentos cadastrados no banco eu só preciso, atualizar a $matricula e a $dataagendamento se eu colocar esse where_in() resolve?

Comment: @web_charles quando vc usa o `where()` normal sua consulta fica assim : `where coluna = valor` com o `where_in()` fica: `where coluna in(elemento1, elemento2 ... N)`